# Is there a way to get Dark Gauntlets after the mimic chest dies but you die before you pick it in Dark Souls 2?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I just recently went on a scavenging hunt and found the dark leggings and chest piece and I went to the location of the gauntlets but it seems as if I already killed it, but I have no dark gauntlets. Is there any way besides restarting to get it?

Comment: You could use a bonfire ascetic. Or ask one of your mates to trade theirs to you

Comment: Ascetic doesn't work

Comment: It should, you can only get the Dark Gear from Mimics - and Mimics respawn with Ascetics...

Answer (score 1):

Dropped Items don't disappear on death. Go to where the mimic is, and get that item!